# Iterate backward and forward in a list conditionally in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I am stuck at a point where I have a list like below:

```
IN022023000',20170101,null,126.0, 230, 110
IN022023000',20170102,null,126.0, null, null
IN022023000',20170103,null,126.0, null, null
IN022023000',20170104,null,126.0, null, null
IN022023000',20170105,null,126.0, 250, 110
```

I am creating this list form a table

```
(stID,sDate,PRCP,TAVG,TMAX,TMIN)
```

Here you can see data for last to column is missing for date `20170103`. I want to implement logic which will fill this missing values based on some rule.

1. If last two value `(TMAX,TMIN)` for a certain date (`20170103`) is missing then move back to the previous date in the list and look for the value for `TMAX` and `TMIN` if present take the value and impute it to the missing date.
2. If moving back gives me missing value as well then I will move one day forward and do the same thing.

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: @U9-Forward please don't add tags you're not sure OP asked for.

Comment: @ Raj, is this using pandas or just pure python?

Comment: @  coldspeed i am using justpython

Comment: Well, good luck with that, because unless you're using a number crunching library, this is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @ coldspeed can you please guide me which library shoukd i use , as i said i am very new to python

Comment: Install pandas and read the documentation

Comment: It's a list? Where are the commas after last element of every line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that null is the same as None, and that your table is a list of lists. I also assume that each element of the initial column is a string literal.
See the script below, which ought to be what you're looking for.

```
null = None
table = [['IN022023000',20170101,null,126.0, 230, 110],
['IN022023000',20170102,null,126.0, null, null],
['IN022023000',20170103,null,126.0, null, null],
['IN022023000',20170104,null,126.0, null, null],
['IN022023000',20170105,null,126.0, 250, 110]]

for i in range(len(table)):
    if table[i][4:6] == [null, null]:
        if i>0 and table[i-1][4:6] != [null, null]:
            table[i][4:6] = table[i-1][4:6]
        elif i < (len(table)-1):
            table[i][4:6] = table[i+1][4:6]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(table)
```

With your given data, the output looks like this.

```
[['IN022023000', 20170101, None, 126.0, 230, 110],
 ['IN022023000', 20170102, None, 126.0, 230, 110],
 ['IN022023000', 20170103, None, 126.0, 230, 110],
 ['IN022023000', 20170104, None, 126.0, 230, 110],
 ['IN022023000', 20170105, None, 126.0, 250, 110]]
```

This is what's great about Python and why it's a good idea to learn it. Once you have it down really well, you can use it to automate all sorts of tasks by writing short little scripts which will end up making your life so much easier.

Comment: @ Cyprian Blunt thanks for the help , just one more thing can i have a flag kind of thing in this loop that i have copied this data from previous date

Comment: @rajNishKuMar This is still Cyprian, although I changed my screen name.
Do you mean keeping another data item per table row, to indicate if the date was taken from a previous row? You can do that. Put the True/False flag at the very end of each row and then when you print the list, instead of doing pprint, just print the first 6 items of each row.
Does that help?

Comment: @ eyelesscactus54 thanks i was able to do that as explained by you very very thankyou,